# Xamarin.Forms: Add Children programmatically to certain column of grid

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a simple grid:

```
                <Grid Grid.Row="5" x:Name="row5_piccat">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ImageButton
                         Aspect="AspectFit"
                         x:Name="btn_dummy_piccat2"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Source="btn_emptydummy.png" BackgroundColor="#00000000"/>

                    <Entry x:Name="entry_descri_pickcate" 
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            FontFamily="arial"
                           MaxLength="50"
                           Placeholder="Kurzbeschreibung" 
                            BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                            TextColor="#272727"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                            VerticalOptions="Center">
                    </Entry>

                </Grid>
```

Now, as you can see, there are layout inside this grid, in coumn 1.

Now I want to exchange the contents of that grid programmatically with a red box:

```
private void SetLayoutForTakers()
{
    btn_dummy_piccat2.IsVisible = false;
    entry_descri_pickcate.IsVisible = false;

    Grid grid = new Grid(); //Neues Grid
    BoxView bx = new BoxView();

    bx.Color = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Red;

    grid.Children.Add(bx);
    row5_piccat.Children.Add(grid);
}
```

But the red box is always set to be inside the first column not in column two (which is number 1 here, since it is 0 based).

How to I adress this specific column where the imagebutton and the entry are already in, disable them (already done) and just show a red box in this colum? (row 0, colum 1)?

Thank yoU:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Grid.Children.Add` has an overload that lets you specify row and column

```
myGrid.Children.Remove(oldView);
myGrid.Children.Add(newView,row,col);
```

Comment: Its myGrid.Children.Add(newView,col,row);

not the other way round

Answer (score 0):

Grid dynamicGrid = new Grid { Padding= new Thickness(5,5)};

```
    dynamicGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()); 
    dynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    dynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

    var label = new Label();
    var entry= new Entry();
    dynamicGrid.Children.Add(label, 0, 0);
    dynamicGrid.Children.Add(entry, 1, 0);
```